# Python: how to instantiate a class "like a data class"?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Data classes have this nice property of a much short / more readable "init function".
Example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class MyClass1:
    x: int = field(default=1)
    y: int = field(default=2)
```

As opposed to:

```
class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self, x : int = 1, y : int = 2):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Here, the code for MyClass1 is shorter because it doesn't need the explicit `"def __init__(...)"` function. Further, the ability to use fields allows for even more control while maintaining readability.

How does that work under the hood, and how can one implement this (and only this) particular syntactic sugar without actually using/importing dataclass?

Comment: You can see the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/dataclasses.py) for `dataclass` yourself. There's no syntactic sugar involved, just a lot of dynamically generated code executed via `exec`.

Comment: There is no syntactic sugar here, everything is standard Python: a decorator, type annotations and a utility function producing a marker object which the decorator looks for.

Comment: Side note: the `field()` objects are redundant here, you can use `x: int = 1` here as the defaults are static and immutable.